# Discord.py-rewrite - How to make the BOT self mute or self deaf in a voice channel?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a Discord BOT using `discord.py-rewrite` and am focusing on the Music part of my BOT. I checked the API several times but I do not know how to make my self mute or self deaf on a voice channel (not server mute or server deafen). Anyone please know how I can self mute or self deaf my discord BOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API doesn't expose this functionality, but there is [a method for doing this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/919dbcafb33eb4e2bb595d7e607f525cf2d02178/discord/gateway.py#L520) in the websocket code

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        return
    channel = voice_client.channel
    await voice_client.main_ws.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_mute=True)
```

I can't test this at the moment, so it may not work.  Keep in mind also that there is no guarantee that internal methods like this won't change even between minor versions.