# How can I deafen a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my music bot to be deafen when joining the channel. But I still want it to play music. I already tried with a `await change_voice_state(*, channel, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)` function and with the discord.py docs, but nothing helped. I work with the `commands.command` method. Here is the relevant part of my source code:

```py
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        """Plays a song from a URL"""

        client = ctx.guild.voice_client
        state = self.get_state(ctx.guild)  # get the guild's state

        send_message = state.now_playing is not None

        # connect to author's voice channel
        if not client:
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                raise commands.CommandError("You have to be in a voice channel.")
            else:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
                client = await channel.connect()
```

`await channel.connect` seems to be the relevant part. I hope I can get help here.

I have seen other docs on the side which work with:

```py
await voice_client.main_ws.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_deaf=True)
```

but I get the following error message: `AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'main_ws'`

My code then looks like:

```py
        if not client:
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                raise commands.CommandError("Du musst in einem Sprachkanal sein, um dies zu tun.")
            else:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

                client = await channel.connect()
                voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
                channel = voice_client.channel
                await voice_client.main_ws.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_deaf=True)
```

Maybe I somewhere made a mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py-rewrite - How to make the BOT self mute or self deaf in a voice channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904739/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-make-the-bot-self-mute-or-self-deaf-in-a-voice-chann)

Comment: @Sneftel I have seen this one. I tried nearly everything out that was also written here. However here is what I did: 
`client = await channel.connect() , voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
channel = voice_client.channel - await voice_client.main_ws.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_deaf=True)`

Which gives me the following error: `AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'main_ws'` so do I have to change it to a `guild` thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you can try to use the following:

```py
await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_deaf=True)
```

I would also recommend adding and set `self_mute` to `False` to guarantee that the bot is playing music if that is what you want.

To sum it up, here is the code you can try:

```py
await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=channel, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)
```